# Message text for ferror() return value

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, io

How can I get the message for error codes returned by `int ferror(FILE*)`? For `errno` there is the `char * strerror(int)`. What is it for codes returned by ferror? If `char * strerror(int)` is good for that too, then I need a reference for it (I failed to find any indicator for this case).

Comment: `ferror` only tells you if the stream's error indicator is set. You can't get an error message from it. (At least not portably.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [this reference page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ferror.html):

> The *ferror()* function shall test the error indicator for the stream pointed to by stream.

This means that `ferror` returns a boolean that tells you if there is an error or not, nothing more. But according to the POSIX specification the value of `errno` will contain an error code in case of a failure.

Comment: Just for a note. [man ferror](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ferror): _These functions should not fail and do not set the external variable errno._

Comment: "All standard FILE* function also set errno on error" — I don't doubt this, but I'm unable to find any documentation of it. The C library reference at cppreference.com makes no mention of it (e.g. [fwrite](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite)), nor do my local macOS man pages, nor online Linux man pages. The only statement about errno I've found is the guarantee that `ferror` does _not_ set it.

Comment: Update: The [OpenGroup spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html) does document it: "if a write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, [CX] [Option Start]  and errno shall be set to indicate the error." Seems like an important thing to leave out of all the other documentation.

Comment: @JensAlfke Note that [the C standard states](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3): "The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard."  That means that if a function is NOT documented to set `errno`, it's free to munge the value in any way it might desire.  So if your implementation and the C standard doesn't document the use of `errno` for a function, you can't rely on it to remain unchanged if you call that function.

Answer (score 3):

The library `libexplain` can return strings for the ferror. https://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_ferror
From the docs:

```
if (ferror(fp) < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", explain_ferror(fp));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Do you know why the example here is testing for less than 0, when the ferror manpage only says nonzero indicates error?

Comment: @idij That is sample code from the referenced manual. On the other hand: you should do error handling on positive error codes as well. Oh the third hand: """Note: This function is not thread safe, because it shares a return buffer across all threads, and many other functions in this library. """. Which means that for a multi-threaded application you need an external global mutex and copying the contents of that buffer before releasing the mutex. And making sure that none of the libraries you depend on use this function. I would say rarely worth it.